# How many liters is my pool

Tags: mathematics

My pool is full with water and I'm using a 20 liter bucket to empty the pool.

If I could use a 25 liter bucket I would have to scoop 12 buckets less.

How many liters is my pool?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is

> 1200 liters

How:

> This is pretty trivial, because notice that for every 100 liters, it will take one less scoop using a 25 liter bucket than it will when using a 20 liter bucket.
> It is then to be noted that 1200 liters is needed to be in your pool to satisfy the constraint of needing to use the 25 liter bucket 12 less times than the 20 liter bucket (48 times using the 25 liter bucket compared to 60 using the 20 liter bucket)

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.